# Python zero-values

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

Are there any values other than  `False`, `None`, `0`, and `0.0` that will return False with `bool(x)` (in Python 3.X)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: What I was looking for. >_> Thanks. I should probably refer to that resource more often.

Answer (score 3):

Any empty sequence or mapping object will also evaluate to `False`:

```
>>> bool({})
False
>>> bool([])
False
>>> bool("")
False
>>> bool(())
False
```